# Making a matrix in R without typing out specific elements, excluding some

Tags: r

[image: The Matrix]

How do I make a matrix with the sequence 1:16, where all values except 2,3,6,9 and 16 are equal to 0?

I've tried a bunch of different things.

Comment: Try `matrix(replace(1:16, !1:16 %in% c(2, 3, 6, 9, 16), 0), 4, 4)`

Comment: @akrun that is shorter than what I suggested - but it needs `byrow=TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```r
m1  <- 1:16
m2  <- rep(0, 16)
indices  <- c(2,3,6,9,16)

m2[indices]  <- m1[indices]

matrix(m2, nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    2    3    0
# [2,]    0    6    0    0
# [3,]    9    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0   16
```

Depends if the values you want to be non-zero are always going to be at their indices when the matrix is created by row.

You can generalise this method into a function:

```r
create_matrix  <- function(max_val, nrow, non_zero_indices) {    
    m1  <- 1:max_val
    m2  <- rep(0, max_val)

    m2[non_zero_indices]  <- m1[non_zero_indices]

    matrix(m2, nrow = nrow, byrow = TRUE)
}

create_matrix(16,4, c(2,3,6,9,16))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    2    3    0
# [2,]    0    6    0    0
# [3,]    9    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0   16
```

@akrun's suggestion in the comments will also work if you add `byrow=TRUE`, so it looks like:

```r
matrix(replace(1:16, !1:16 %in% c(2, 3, 6, 9, 16), 0), 4, 4, byrow=TRUE)
```

It's a matter of taste.

### EDIT: Generation of indices

No one asked for this but I noticed that your indices follow a sequence - specifically they are [OEIS A081660](https://oeis.org/A081660) + 1. So instead of typing them directly you could generate them with:

```r
get_indices  <- function(n) {
     2^(n+1)/3+n+(-1)^n/3 + 1
}

get_indices(0:4) 
# [1]  2  3  6  9 16
```